# How to add a body background color to php, html email template

Tags: php, html, css, html-email

So I have a confirmation email templates that is being sent with a white body background but I would like to make it gray but I am not sure how to add this in the php file where the email function below is

```
$headers = "From: " . stripslashes_deep( html_entity_decode( $from_name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ) ) . " <$from_email>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "\r\n";
//$headers  .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers = apply_filters( 'give_admin_donation_notification_headers', $headers, $payment_id, $payment_data );

$attachments = apply_filters( 'give_admin_donation_notification_attachments', array(), $payment_id, $payment_data );

$message = give_get_donation_notification_body_content( $payment_id, $payment_data );
```

Can I just add an html body color tag anywhere after the header?

This is the code in give_get_donation_notification_body_content

```
function give_get_donation_notification_body_content( $payment_id = 0, $payment_data = array() ) {

$user_info = maybe_unserialize( $payment_data['user_info'] );
$email     = give_get_payment_user_email( $payment_id );

if ( isset( $user_info['id'] ) && $user_info['id'] > 0 ) {
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_info['id'] );
    $name      = $user_data->display_name;
} elseif ( isset( $user_info['first_name'] ) && isset( $user_info['last_name'] ) ) {
    $name = $user_info['first_name'] . ' ' . $user_info['last_name'];
} else {
    $name = $email;
}

$gateway = give_get_gateway_admin_label( get_post_meta( $payment_id, '_give_payment_gateway', true ) );

$default_email_body = esc_html__( 'Hello', 'give' ) . "\n\n";
$default_email_body .= esc_html__( 'A donation has been made.', 'give' ) . "\n\n";
/* translators: %s: form plural label */
$default_email_body .= sprintf( esc_html__( '%s sold:', 'give' ), give_get_forms_label_plural() ) . "\n\n";
$default_email_body .= esc_html__( 'Donor:', 'give' ) . ' ' . html_entity_decode( $name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ) . "\n";
$default_email_body .= esc_html__( 'Amount:', 'give' ) . ' ' . html_entity_decode( give_currency_filter( give_format_amount( give_get_payment_amount( $payment_id ) ) ), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ) . "\n";
$default_email_body .= esc_html__( 'Payment Method:', 'give' ) . ' ' . $gateway . "\n\n";
$default_email_body .= esc_html__( 'Thank you', 'give' );

$email = give_get_option( 'donation_notification' );
$email = isset( $email ) ? stripslashes( $email ) : $default_email_body;

$email_body = give_do_email_tags( $email, $payment_id );

return apply_filters( 'give_donation_notification', wpautop( $email_body ), $payment_id, $payment_data );
```

}

Comment: `give_get_donation_notification_body_content()` contains the email contents, which should include the html you need to alter

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I found function give_get_donation_notification_body_content( $payment_id = 0, $payment_data = array() ) { in different document but it does not contain a <body> tag so I can add my stile

Comment: can you add code of function `give_get_donation_notification_body_content(..,..)`

Comment: I have edited my question, please check it.

Comment: does not look like its actually sending html formatted email

Answer (score 0):

Your question is "How to add html color tags in body email", isnt?

in my experience send email as html using PHP. 
first We need to know from our client:

1. your client OS : win, linux, android, mac, iphone etc
2. your client email application: thunderbird, firefox browser, chrome browser, Ms outlook, etc
3. you client EMAIL server: gmail, yahoo, etc

everything have different issue. to know more about this, you can read this link https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

so the best you can do is "Design the best looks for all email client as possible as you can"

and your question is

1. "Can i add background color in email template?"

Answer: yes you can

2. "Can i add Class/ID in HTML tag then use CSS for styling them?"

Answer: Yes, you can, but several email server will not allow you to doing that like gmail

3. "can i styling <*body>, and wrote something in <*head> or maybe just write <*html>?"

Answer: Yes, you can, but prevent to write <*html>, <*body>, <*head>, just start with div or your content directly.

so the best way is styling every html tag with inline style

```
$default_email_body = "<div style=\"background-color: grey;\">
<h1 style=\"color: red;\">email title</h1>
<p style=\"font-size: 8px;\">body emailllllllllllllllllll</p>
</div>";
```

try to send that HTML